# jscrollbar show other components

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

Good evening everyone;

I java swing i am trying to have a menu like in the picture

(in the picture left side)

[image]

However, it appears that it is more difficult than i thought.I had border layout and i put box layout in the middle and jscroll bar for the right side. Inside the box layout i but labels with icons and i try to chance visibility with adjustment level event. However, i could not manage to obtain any results. I made a research on the internet and stackoverflow however, again i could not exactly reach my purpose.

Regards ...

Answer (score 2):

`JScrollBar`s are not typically used alone, they are used in conjunction with `JScrollPane`.

[image]

Basically, you want to add you components to a container of some kind (say a `JPanel`) with an appropriate layout manager, then set that container as the view within a `JScrollPane`

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: I have a absolute layout and this absolute layout includes border layout which includes a JscrollPane component.However, if i put jlabels to them i am not able to see labels. Labels are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer inspiring from comments of other users. First of all thank you for having a look to my question.

i used the codes in here;

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpleJScrollPanedemonstration.htm

problem is i required to create a container and put the items to container and then take that pane to put jscroolpane.

Regards ...